# Fetch value from a nested Json using Karate framework

Tags: karate

I have a following json values.

```
   {
        "TestA": [
        {
           "Condition1": "Value1,
           "Condition2": "Value2",
           "Condition3": "Value3"
       }     
     ],
   "TestB": [
    {
         "Condition11": "Value11,
         "Condition12": "Value12",
         "Condition13": "Value13"
   }
  ],
   "TestC": [
   {
         "Condition21": "Value21,
         "Condition22": "Value22",
          "Condition23": "Value23"
    }
  ]
```

}

I want to get the value of Condition11. (which is value 11).

I tried TestB contains "Value11" it works.

Currently when i use the two options below, they return me the complete nested Json as above and its not what is expected.

i tried TestB.Condition11 == "Value11" , it does not work.
I tried TestB.Condition11[0] == "Value11" it does not work.

Can someone please help in getting the value by using the == option and not contains.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the documentation. Here below is just one way, there are many ways to do this:

```
* def value = get[0] response..Condition11
* print value
```

Refer https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#jsonpath-filters